# jQuery - fancybox conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have my site in: 
`http://210.48.94.218/~zealandt/book-a-tattoo/`

My jQuery code in map coordinates is successfully running the fancybox.
However, the links' fancybox (city links) below the map are conflicting with jquery. 
Each link must show the popup similar with map coordinate popup.

**Q: How can I make my jQuery code to not conflict with the fancyBox's jquery?**

My code to show the pop up of a city link:

```
$('#table-list a').click(function(){
    OutputFancyBox($(this));
});

function OutputFancyBox(element){
fb = jQuery.noConflict();
fb.fancybox({
        href: '#inline-element',
        title: element.attr('title'),
        width    :  popUpWidth,
        height    : 450,
        fitToView    : false,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick    : false,
        openEffect    : 'elastic',
        closeEffect    : 'elastic',
        minHeight:      300,
        onCleanup : function() {
            $('#gform_wrapper_3').css("display","none");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: have you tried commenting out the option `onCleanup`? (which is not a valid option for fancybox v2) .. the error you get points out to that line `TypeError: fb.fancybox is not a function
 http://210.48.94.218/~zealandt/book-a-tattoo/
 Line 662` ... funnily you don't use `noConflict` in your other fancybox calls.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks. You can write your answer so that I can accept it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried commenting out the option `onCleanup`? which is not a valid option for fancybox v2.x

The error you get points out to that line :

```
TypeError: fb.fancybox is not a function 
http://210.48.94.218/~zealandt/book-a-tattoo/ 
Line 662
```

You are not using `noConflict` in your other fancybox calls so maybe you don't need it there either.